# How to dynamically change worksheet reference in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working with some financial data - specifically to see if our actual work hours/cost matched our bids.

The higher ups would like to see a summary sheet with one row per project (we run some additional calculations and add notes as to why numbers are not close)

What we get is a sheet with 1 work sheet per project, the bid is always in G81 and the actual is in H81 of every sheet.  Each worksheet is named by the project ID

I have a list of project ID's in column A of my summary sheet.  How can I dynamically look up the sheet based off of column A and pull in the values from G81 or H81?

Comment: Does the sheet name match the project ID in column A of the summary sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the Indirect() function.

So in B2:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!G81")
```

And in Column C:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!H81")
```

then copy down

Comment: No more to add! That is the (only) answer!